# How can I keep my database on an SD card and use ORMLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I use [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) to work with my database, and I faced with problem how keep database on sd card. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629021/android-ormlite-db-location/13111761#13111761

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can simply add the /sdcard/ string before your database name and it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what ORM Lite is and never used it.

However, by default Android will place your database in  /data/data/PACKAGE/databases/DATABASEFILE  on your storage device.  If you don't like that location, you can follow this article and [relocate your database](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)  to wherever you want.