# How to specify DB path for ORMLite and Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

We currently have a SQLite DB for our Android App. We placed it in the SD card (emulated most of times). Now we are moving to ORMLite but dont know how to tell the ORM that it should use a specific path and even (if possible) that we want to keep running using our existing DB file (for testing purposes).

How can this be achieved?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13111761/233048

Comment: Yes, something like that. Thanks.